# How to persist communication after shutting down/turning on the device?

Tags: ios, background-process

I'm developing an iOS application to keep track of certain system information from the device. The application is supposed to keep sending information even if it is in background. Everything is working fine but when I shut down the device and then turn it on, the application is still in background but it won't communicate the information. Can someone help me to become active my application after turning on the device?

Answer (score 1):

> when I shut down the device and then turn it on, the application is still in background

No, it isn't. The app launcher **pretends** that it is, but in reality it's been shut down. And there's no way you can re-open it programmatically (even less chance for opening a currently dead process *from within itself....*) - The only reasonable solution I could think of is jailbreaking the device and hooking into SpringBoard so it re-launches all open apps upon reboot, but I don't believe that's a viable option for you.

Comment: The thing is that applications such as Waze and Life360 make this possible. I wonder how they did it. Turning off/on the device isn't an issue for them because they keep the communication going

Answer (score 0):

One way you could achieve this is by the application creating local notifications. These will persist through shutting down the device.

See this fine tutorial: http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/

Comment: That won't reopen the app itself, though.

Comment: It won't open it "automatically", but it can present an alert action that gives the user the option to open the application by interacting with the alert. See this tutorial: http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/

Comment: @picciano thank you but I'm looking for a way to start the application (not launching it necessary